# Front facing Camera Recorded video not proper

Tags: android, video, android-camera

I want to record Video using front facing camera. Using the example from [here](http://android-er.blogspot.com.au/2011/10/simple-exercise-of-video-capture-using.html) as reference. I changed the getCamerainstance method to getFrontFacingCamera. I am able to see the preview while recording. But when i close the recording and play the video, it is always some horizontal flickering lines. Seems like some encoding issue. I tried- changing the media recorder profile to QUALITY_LOW/ QUALITY_HIGH, - Setting the frame rate to 15. the same app works perfectly when i use rear camera.

P.S: I have set the preview's(surface view's) size to 208×208. (Should this affect? , It's working fine with rear camera).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it. (In case someone faces the same issue)

need to  use: mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(320,240);